# PHP Get Data From MySQLI [delete this]

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

Hello I'm trying to get live data from sql table, example if one rows is inserted show me with data like notification system

with my code when i insert new row not fetch me... !?

index.php:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(
            function() {updateChat();},
            1000);

            function updateChat() {
                $.get("read.php", function(data)
                {
                  $("#Show_Data").html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div id="Show_Data"></div>
```

read.php

```
include('config.php');

$sql_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM shout_box where id > 15 ORDER BY id");

while($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo 'ID: ' .$fetch_data['id']. ' Text: '. $fetch_data['text']. '</br>';
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

[image]

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: So what is problem?

Comment: i want to fetch every second data like live system

Comment: Please edit your question for clarification too.

Comment: @SimpleName So what you're saying is it's working the first time, but it's not working after you add new data to the system, correct?

Comment: What are you seeing in the response from `read.php`? You can see it in your developer tools in chrome/firefox/ie by going to the Requests tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
var myCall = setInterval(updateChat, 1000);

//for to stop calling
function myStopFunction() {
   clearInterval(myCall);
}
```

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Comment: how can i stop beacouse div is refresh every second !!! i se with inspect element

Comment: work fine but now i insert new row and dont show me this cod is not live system

Comment: can i make this bro ?

Answer (score 0):

it's a dirty job but fine.
you must not get ALL data from database every 1s. there is huge data after a long chat.
so you can save last row id that you get from db in an attribute. then after 1s you must check all rows after that id or after that time (i see u have a date_time for every row).